# Finding the smallest divisor

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find the smallest divisor of $ 12!+6!+12!\cdots6!+1!$ except 1

I know this has to do something with Wilson's theorem which states the if $n$ is a prime number $n$ will divide $(n-1)!+1$.

Comment: Isn't $1$ the smallest divisor of all integers ?

Comment: I believe you mean the smallest divisor greater than $1$ of $12!+6!+12!*6!+1!$ What is the $/$ doing there?  Can you factor the expression?

Comment: ah nothing just some bad editing lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is straightforward to check that 1 to 6 are no divisors of the expression, since they are factors of $12!$, $6!$ and $12!6!$.

Further, 7 is a divisior of both $12!$ and $12!6!$. Because $$12!=1\cdot2\cdot3\ldots6\cdot\color{blue}{7}\cdot8\ldots 11\cdot12$$

By Wilson's theorem, we have $$ 6! \equiv -1 \mod 7$$

so $6!+1$ is also divisible by 7. Therefore $7 \mid 12!6!+12!+6!+1$

Answer (score 1):

$12!+6!+12!6!+1!=(12!+1)(6!+1)=(13^2\cdot 2834329)(7\cdot 103)$.